# What is the right way to toggle a value inside object state in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Here is a simple code sample to toggle a button

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const initialState = {
  isOpen: true
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, _setState] = useState(initialState);
  const setState = newState =>
    _setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...newState }));

  const toggleButton = () => {
    setState({ isOpen: !state.isOpen });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggleButton}>Show</button>
      {state.isOpen && <h1>Hello World</h1>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Questions**

1. Is the above code is the right way to toggle a value inside an object?
2. Is there any advantage if I change the `toggleButton` function to code below? By not accessing `state` object reference when `setState` executes.

```
const toggleButton = () => {
    const { isOpen } = state;
    setState({ isOpen: !isOpen });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Questions**

> 1. Is the above code is the right way to toggle a value inside an object?

This is *maybe* debatable, but the correct way to toggle *any* react state is to use a functional state update. This is because multiple state updates can be enqueued and batch processed. You want them to process in the order in which they are queued and end with the correct state.

```
const toggleButton = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({ isOpen: !prevState.isOpen }));
};
```

The following is a demo I use to demonstrate why functional updates work.

[image: Edit react - regular and functional state updates]

> 2. Is there any advantage if I change the toggleButton function to code below? By not accessing state object reference when setState executes.
>
> ```
> const toggleButton = () => {
>   const { isOpen } = state;
>   setState({ isOpen: !isOpen });
> };
> ```

No, not really, it's still directly accessing the current state object that is enclosed in the callback function scope.

Comment: What if `initialState` has more than one boolean? Lets add `show` to `initialState`. Do I need to write separate callbacks to toggle each? Like `const toggleShow = () => { setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, show: !prevState.show}) )}` and `const toggleShow = () => { setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, show: !prevState.show}) )}` . OR should I declare both boolean as separate state and use their setters? What is the recommended way? I think the second looks goods if we are on to write separate toggle callbacks.

Comment: @NiyasNazar Yes, functional component `useState` hook doesn't merge state updates like the class-based components' `setState` does, so you'd need to shallowly merge in the rest of state manually. For this reason it is generally recommended to break your state apart and use separate hooks for each "piece" of state. This is *only* a suggestion and not a hard rule, sometimes it makes sense to store state in a single variable (*think a form with a bunch of inputs*), so use your best judgement. IMO, I like the second way as well for toggles.

Answer (score 0):

Since React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance, it is better to get the previous state than accessing it directly

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

This would be the correct form of doing it

```
setState(prevState => ({
  isOpen: !prevState.isOpen
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

with Hooks you could do this:

```html
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

  const [isOpen, useIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleButton = () => {
    useIsOpen((prevState) => {
      return {isOpen: !prevState.isOpen};
    })
  }

  return (
  <div className="App">
  <button onClick={toggleButton}>Show</button>
  </div>
  );
}
```

or alternatively you could :

```html
export default function App() {
  const [isOpen, useIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleButton = () => useIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
  <div className="App">
  <button onClick={toggleButton}>Show</button>
  </div>
  );
}
```